# Split into xml files retaining few tags from base xml file using linq

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have this xml and want to split to individual xml files based on the `<order>` tag count retaining few tags from base xml.Since I am new to play with xml and linq, I was just searching in google and questions on stack overflow didnt meet my requirements.

```
<OrderList>
<Source>xml</Source>
<Organisation>org</Organisation>
<CreationDate>12/14/2015</CreationDate>
<Orders>
 <Order>
    <Name> Mobile </Name>
    <Price> 50.00</Price>
    <Quantity> 1 </Quantity>
 </Order>
  <Order>
    <Name> Accessories </Name>
    <Price> 50.00</Price>
    <Quantity> 5 </Quantity>
 </Order>
 </Orders>
</OrderList>
```

So File1.xml should be

```
<OrderList>
<Source>xml</Source>
<Organisation>org</Organisation>
<CreationDate>12/14/2015</CreationDate>
<Orders>
 <Order>
    <Name> Mobile </Name>
    <Price> 50.00</Price>
    <Quantity> 1 </Quantity>
 </Order>
 </Orders>
 </OrderList>
```

File2.xml

```
<OrderList>
<Source>xml</Source>
<Organisation>org</Organisation>
<CreationDate>12/14/2015</CreationDate>
<Orders>
 <Order>
    <Name> Accessories </Name>
    <Price> 50.00</Price>
    <Quantity> 5 </Quantity>
 </Order>
 </Orders>
 </OrderList>
```

Previous questions in stackoverflow explains to split the tags into xml file but I want to retain few values from base file also.Can any please help with this with Linq and XElement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to split the `Orders` in two `OrderList` you can try something like this, *you will dont need to create the same node, it will be copied from ordersXML, and the new `Orders` will be created*:

```
XElement ordersXML = XElement.Parse(XML_ORDERS);        
var ordersElement = ordersXML.Element("Orders");
var orders = ordersElement.Elements("Order");
var newOrdersList = orders.Select(x => new XStreamingElement("OrderList", ordersXML.Elements().Where(e => e.Name!="Orders"), new XElement("Orders",x)));
```

So see my [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/2g8iqj).

Comment: Can you explain me how to use with XPathselectElement as well? I tried since it has namespace, but not retaining the few tags from base xml

Comment: I suggest you to see this examples: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms256086(v=vs.110).aspx , and try on this http://www.webtoolkitonline.com/xml-xpath-tester.html